# No digraphs available in vim

Tags: vim, digraphs

I can't get digraphs to work in vim.

When I type:

```
:digraphs
```

it gives me an error message: E196: No digraphs in this version.

Do I need to install any plugins or packages? If I type:

```
:scriptnames
```

it doesn't seem to return i.e. just seems to block.

I am using vim 8.2.587 in Fedora 30, running as a guest inside Virtual Box.

When using vim 8.2.158 running on a native Fedora 31 machine, the digraphs work fine.

Update:

```
vi --version | grep digraph
```

shows that vim  was built with digraph support. The full output is below.

```
> vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Apr 17 2020 05:09:15)
Included patches: 1-587
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_old_static
-arabic            -file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_any_white
+autocmd           -find_in_path      -mouse_urxvt       -tcl
-autochdir         -float             +mouse_xterm       -termguicolors
-autoservername    -folding           +multi_byte        -terminal
-balloon_eval      -footer            -multi_lang        +terminfo
-balloon_eval_term +fork()            -mzscheme          +termresponse
-browse            -gettext           -netbeans_intg     -textobjects
+builtin_terms     -hangul_input      +num64             -textprop
-byte_offset       +iconv             -packages          -timers
-channel           +insert_expand     -path_extra        -title
-cindent           -ipv6              -perl              -toolbar
-clientserver      -job               -persistent_undo   +user_commands
-clipboard         +jumplist          -popupwin          -vartabs
+cmdline_compl     -keymap            -printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist      -lambda            -profile           +virtualedit
-cmdline_info      -langmap           -python            +visual
+comments          -libcall           -python3           +visualextra
-conceal           -linebreak         -quickfix          -viminfo
-cryptv            -lispindent        -reltime           +vreplace
-cscope            +listcmds          -rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorbind        +localmap          -ruby              -wildmenu
-cursorshape       -lua               +scrollbind        +windows
-dialog            -menu              -signs             +writebackup
-diff              -mksession         -smartindent       -X11
-digraphs          +modify_fname      -sound             -xfontset
-dnd               +mouse             -spell             -xim
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        -startuptime       -xpm
-emacs_tags        -mouse_dec         -statusline        -xsmp
-eval              -mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -syntax            -xterm_save
-extra_search      -mouse_netterm     +tag_binary        
   system vimrc file: "/etc/virc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.virc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/virc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim82"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-z,relro  -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm  -lselinux -lncurses -lacl -lattr -ldl
```

Comment: what does `vim --version | grep digraphs` say?

Comment: If it says "E196" then it was compiled without digraphs support. Get proper version, complain to those who built this one, etc.

Comment: @Matt, @'Docktor OSwaldo' It looks like vi was built with digraph support - see the update to the OP above.

Comment: @John How do you think it was if it clearly says `-digraphs`?

Comment: @John matt is correct. The `-` sign indicates that there is no `digraphs` support compiled into your version of vim. You will have to get a different version or build vim yourself!

Comment: Sorry - didn't notice the -/+ The solution was to install the "vim-enhanced" package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Small version without GUI` and `-digraphs` speak a clear language here. Many Linux distributions just ship with a minimal, stripped-down version of Vim to provide `vi` compatibility. If you want to use the full Vim capabilities, you typically can install a separate package (usually named `vim`, or `vim-full` vs. the default `vim-tiny`). And that would then be invoked as `vim`, not `vi`.